# How to embed Facebook Messenger into a Gatsby Site?

Tags: javascript, facebook, gatsby, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to embed Facebook Messenger into a Gatsby site. In Chrome's Inspector I can see a div with id="fb-root" however its height is 0 (width is the width of the viewport) and the chat widget is not appearing.

After using the setup tool in my Facebook page's Settings -> Messaging -> Add Messenger to your website, it generates some html code, which can't be used in a Gatsby (or any React Framework) site.

With the code I can create a custom component called MessengerChat.js with the following:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function MessengerChat() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      window.FB.init({
        xfbml: true,
        version: "v10.0",
      });
    };
    (function (d, s, id) {
      var js,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div id="fb-root" />
      <div
        className="fb-customerchat"
        attribution="page_inbox"
        page_id="XXXXXXX"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default MessengerChat;
```

Then, in gatsby-browser.js I can use the following code:

```
import MessengerChat from "./src/MessengerChat";

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => (
  <>
    {element}
    <MessengerChat />
  </>
);
```

Can anyone help in suggesting why the app might not be displaying correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `MessengerChat` loses its constraints because of the `wrapPageElement` wrapping. Try:

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => (
      return <Layout {...props}>
                 {element}
                 <MessengerChat />
             </Layout>
    
    }
```

Keep in mind that `wrapPageElement` needs to be set as well in the `gatsby-ssr.js`, as you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement):

> Note: There is an equivalent hook in Gatsby’s [SSR API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/ssr-apis/#wrapRootElement). It is
> recommended to use both APIs together. For example usage, check out
> [Using redux](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux).

If using Layout is not suitable for your use-case, try adding manually a height to your `MessengerChat` using CSS.

Comment: Hi Ferran, thanks for replying, appreciate it. I've created a gatsby-ssr.js following the examples in the docs. Unfortunately, Layout isn't suitable in my set up so I've tried manually adding height to the "fb-root" div. At the bottom of every page now is a blank space at the height I've added. I've checked the network tab, xfbml.customerchat.js is being downloaded, not sure why nothing is being rendered.

Comment: What's the output if you just run  `return <div>{element}<MessengerChat /></Layout>`

Comment: So, to confirm, I now have a wrapPageElement.js at root level which contains: const wrapPageElement = {{ element }} => ( <div>{element}<MessengerChat /></div>); 
This is being exported into both gatsby-browser.js and gatsby-ssr.js as:

import CustomLayout from "./wrapPageElement";
export const wrapPageElement = CustomLayout;

On running a development build I'm still seeing a white space at the bottom of each page

Comment: Can you provide a Codesandbox?

Comment: Hi Ferran, I've just made a small codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-river-jyyz5?file=/wrapPageElement.js

The files are MessengerChat.js, gatsby-browser.js, gatsby-ssr.js and wrapPageElement.js. I've given the facebook div a style of red and height of 60px just so you can see it. In Inspector you can see all the facebook code is there.

Thanks once again for all your help!

Comment: I guess your code is working however, I think that the browser may be blocking your requests. Look at the Network tab. https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-rain-xp7n4?file=/gatsby-browser.js

Comment: Interesting, okay thanks Ferran. I'll try putting it into a production branch and see if it works on a few different browsers

Comment: So, Ferran was correct! The chat widget is blocked on localhost and if you're using deploy previews or a test url to test your site before deployment, you need to make sure that domain is whitelisted in your Facebook page's settings.

Comment: If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue

Comment: I can get this to work in iPhone, and in all desktop browsers (except Firefox Private Window), but not at all in Android.

Comment: Check the privacy or the logs that outputs. Try simulating the Android device on the browser (it's a simulation but it may give you a first approach)